# onActivityResult Not Being Called For UnityPlayerActivity

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, aar

I don't have a lot of experience creating Java (.aar) plugins for Unity3d, but I am attempting to setup google authentication with firebase from such a plugin. To give an example of my problem, I begin by opening a unity android application, then I run the c# code below, and get a popup on my display to sign-in with google. I then choose the correct google account, then the google intent/activity disappears, then I receive no indication that "onActivityResult" has been called. No errors occur and I am unable to to do anything with the google account information that I chose.

In the image below, I click submit -> it opens the google sign-in activity in the next picture -> then it returns back to the submit screen (closing the google sign-in activity).
[image][image]

I think my issue is in this line:

```
activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

The "activity" in this case is a UnityPlayerActivity sent from the c# unity code below. I think this is making it so my code is looking for an "onActivityResult" method in the C# unity code rather than the java code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need any other info or screenshots. Please call me out if I am being a moron.

Here is my code for calling the Google Signin Plugin From C# & Unity3d:

```
        AndroidJNIHelper.debug = true; 
        using (AndroidJavaClass activityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {
            activity_context = activityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        }
        using (AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.package.class")) {
            if (pluginClass != null) {
                GoogleSignInActivity = pluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
                GoogleSignInActivity.Call("SetContext", activity_context);
                GoogleSignInActivity.Call("StartGoogleLogin", activity_context);

                activity_context.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() => {
                    GoogleSignInActivity.Call("ShowMessage", "You signed in as " + display_name);
                }));
            }
        }
```

Here is the code for creating the Google SignIn Activity:

```
public void StartGoogleLogin(UnityPlayerActivity activity) {
    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("some url")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity, gso);

    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    Log.d(TAG, "Activity Started; Waiting For Result");
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "Result Received!");

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            someMethod(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.d(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
        }
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved my own problem of getting Google Authentication to work between the Android .aar plugin and Unity c#. Been working tirelessly and found some kickbutt resources.

First and foremost, I referenced the code written by a guy named cwgtech [HERE](https://github.com/cwgtech/AndroidActivityResult).

I also went through all of his [videos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCdrrB0J4ovI4xQkqiK4HEiw/videos).

Instead of using UnitySendMessage, I was able to use a callback method similar to what CWGTech does to send a googleIdToken back to Unity and sign-in with Google into Firebase. I was also correct in thinking that my mistake was with the statement below:

```
activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Instead of doing this, I followed CWGTech's advice and removed "activity." portion. I ran the startActivityForResult in a ResultCallback class that extends Activity. If you are still confused, dm me or comment on this post. Thanks!

Here is some of the code I used to send a callback string to Unity via a Java Proxy in written in C#. Information about writing a Java proxy can be found in the cwgtech information above. Writing the java proxy is extremely important if you want to get information to flow from Android activities to Unity C#. CWGTech explains the intricacies of java proxies way better than I could do justice.

```
public static final String LOGTAG = GoogleSignInActivity.TAG + "_OnResult";
public static GoogleSignInActivity.ShareStringCallback shareStringCallback;

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
private GoogleSignInOptions gso;

private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

public void myFinish(String myresult) {

    if (shareStringCallback != null) {
        shareStringCallback.onLoginComplete(myresult);
    }

    shareStringCallback = null;
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "onCreateBundle");
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);
    findViewById(R.id.buttonFacebookLogin).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.signInButton).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.buttonAnonymousSignIn).setOnClickListener(this);
}

/* GOOGLE SIGN-IN CODE */
public Intent StartGoogleLogin() {
    /*
    Google Sign In Client Init Code Goes Here
    */
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    return signInIntent;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //Detects some type of result from an activity, in this case Google
    String id_result = "Send This To Unity";
    myFinish(id_result);
}
```

Here is a bit more code from a different java class file. The 'Login' method is called from Unity c#.

```
/* INTERFACES FOR CALLBACK FUNCTIONAILITY */
public interface ShareStringCallback {
    public void onLoginComplete(String result);
}

public void Login(final ShareStringCallback callback)
{
    mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.i(TAG,"Starting Authentication");

                try {
                    try {
                        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        shareIntent.setClass(mainActivity,OnResultCallback.class);
                        OnResultCallback.shareStringCallback = callback;
                        mainActivity.startActivity(shareIntent);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i(TAG,"error sharing intent: " + e);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i(TAG,"Error getting Uri: " + e);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i(TAG,"Error writing file: " + e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey... I have been trying to use an Android speech plugin for unity but  my onActivityResult callback is not working similar to yours.... Can you please give a detailed explanation which i could follow...Dm me please

Comment: @alamshahbaz16497 I posted a bit more code above to help. The code is used to callback to the c# Unity side from Android studio java code. I would recommend watching the videos by cwgtech that I posted above. They helped me out a ton. Let me know if this helps and what type of problem you are running into?

Comment: beautiful solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you start a activity from UnityPlayerActivity, the onActivityResult will be called when finished, but will have its default return value. What you can do is create a new Activity in Android, and extends UnityPlayerActivity.

1. In Android, create a new Activity

```
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;

public class OverrideUnityPlayerActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public Activity getCurrentActivity(){
        return mUnityPlayer.currentActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    //do something
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    //do something
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. You need to set this override activity as launch endpoint in AndroidManifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">
        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.unitylibrary.manager.OverrideUnityPlayerActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="app_name" android:value="app_value"/>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

3.Then in Unity, you can get this activity and context, also get the onActivityResult

```
AndroidJavaObject overridePlayerActivity;
AndroidJavaObject overrideActivity;

public void init(){
    overridePlayerActivity = new AndroidJavaObject("com.example.unitylibrary.manager.OverrideUnityPlayerActivity");
    overrideActivity= overridePlayerActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getCurrentActivity");
}

public void startAct(){
    anonymousFunction.Call("StartActForRes", overrideActivity);
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.